# How to solve the Elevated button on pressed problem in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I am getting user data from firebase firestore and acting on that data in the form of a `List` to create a chatroom using the currentUser and the otherUser as chatRoomID. However, anytime I get the data and click on the button, I get this error:

```
W/ample.badbaado( 5814): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putInt(Ljava/lang/Object;JI)V (greylist, linking, allowed)
W/ample.badbaado( 5814): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putLong(Ljava/lang/Object;JJ)V (greylist, linking, allowed)
W/ample.badbaado( 5814): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getObject(Ljava/lang/Object;J)Ljava/lang/Object; (greylist, linking, allowed)
W/ample.badbaado( 5814): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getInt(Ljava/lang/Object;J)I (greylist, linking, allowed)
W/ample.badbaado( 5814): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putInt(Ljava/lang/Object;JI)V (greylist, linking, allowed)
I/chatty  ( 5814): uid=10151(com.example.badbaadoo) FirestoreWorker identical 2 lines
W/ample.badbaado( 5814): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putInt(Ljava/lang/Object;JI)V (greylist, linking, allowed)
W/ample.badbaado( 5814): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putObject(Ljava/lang/Object;JLjava/lang/Object;)V (greylist, linking, allowed)
W/ample.badbaado( 5814): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putInt(Ljava/lang/Object;JI)V (greylist, linking, allowed)

════════ Exception caught by gesture ═══════════════════════════════════════════
The following RangeError was thrown while handling a gesture:
RangeError (end): Invalid value: Only valid value is 0: 1

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack
#0      RangeError.checkValidRange (dart:core/errors.dart:338:9)
#1      _StringBase.substring (dart:core-patch/string_patch.dart:400:27)
#2      _SearchScreenState.getChatRoomId
#3      _SearchScreenState.createChatRoom
#4      _SearchScreenState.searchTile.<anonymous closure>
#5      _InkResponseState._handleTap
#6      GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback
#7      TapGestureRecognizer.handleTapUp
#8      BaseTapGestureRecognizer._checkUp
#9      BaseTapGestureRecognizer.acceptGesture
#10     GestureArenaManager.sweep
#11     GestureBinding.handleEvent
#12     GestureBinding.dispatchEvent
#13     RendererBinding.dispatchEvent
#14     GestureBinding._handlePointerEventImmediately
#15     GestureBinding.handlePointerEvent
#16     GestureBinding._flushPointerEventQueue
#17     GestureBinding._handlePointerDataPacket
#21     _invoke1 (dart:ui/hooks.dart:169:10)
#22     PlatformDispatcher._dispatchPointerDataPacket (dart:ui/platform_dispatcher.dart:293:7)
#23     _dispatchPointerDataPacket (dart:ui/hooks.dart:88:31)
(elided 3 frames from dart:async)
Handler: "onTap"
Recognizer: TapGestureRecognizer#8bdce
    debugOwner: GestureDetector
    state: ready
    won arena
    finalPosition: Offset(308.0, 194.9)
    finalLocalPosition: Offset(29.3, 30.9)
    button: 1
    sent tap down
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

The button is supposed  to send a user to the conversation screen.
This is the sample code:

```
class _SearchScreenState extends State<SearchScreen> {
  final Database _database = Database();
  final searchUsernameController = new TextEditingController();

  Widget searchTile({
    String userName,
    String userEmail,
    BuildContext context,
  }) {
    // final ThemeData themeData = Theme.of(context);
    return Container(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 24, vertical: 16),
      child: Row(
        children: [
          Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Text(
                userName,
                style: const TextStyle(overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis),
              ),
              addVertical(6.5),
              SizedBox(
                width: 250,
                child: Text(
                  userEmail,
                  style: const TextStyle(overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          const Spacer(),
          ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              createChatRoom(userName: userName);
            },
            child: const Text("Message"),
            style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                horizontal: 16.0,
                vertical: 8.0,
              ),
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25),
              ),
              primary: Colors.blue,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    initiateSearch();
    searchUsernameController.addListener(() {
      final String message = searchUsernameController.text;
      searchUsernameController.value = searchUsernameController.value.copyWith(
        text: message,
        selection: TextSelection(
          baseOffset: message.length,
          extentOffset: message.length,
        ),
        composing: TextRange.empty,
      );
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    searchUsernameController.dispose();
    initiateSearch();
    super.dispose();
  }

  QuerySnapshot searchSnapshot;

  initiateSearch() {
    _database.getUsersByUsername(searchUsernameController.text).then((val) => {
          setState(() {
            searchSnapshot = val;
          }),
        });
  }

  createChatRoom({String userName}) {
    if (userName != UtilConstants.myName) {
      String chatRoomID = getChatRoomId(userName, UtilConstants.myName);
      List<String> users = [
        userName,
        UtilConstants.myName,
      ];

      Map<String, dynamic> chatRoomMap = {
        "users": users,
        "chatRoomID": chatRoomID,
      };
      _database.createChatRoom(chatRoomID, chatRoomMap);
      Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => const ChatDetail(
              // userName: userName,
              ),
        ),
      );
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }

  Widget searchList() {
    return searchSnapshot != null
        ? ListView.builder(
            itemCount: searchSnapshot.docs.length,
            shrinkWrap: true,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              return searchTile(
                userEmail: searchSnapshot.docs[index].get("email"),
                userName: searchSnapshot.docs[index].get("name"),
              );
            },
          )
        : Container();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final ThemeData themeData = Theme.of(context);
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        elevation: 0.0,
        centerTitle: true,
        leading: IconButton(
          onPressed: () async {
            Navigator.pop(context);
          },
          icon: const Icon(
            Icons.arrow_back_ios_outlined,
            size: 23,
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
        ),
        actions: [
          IconButton(
            icon: const Icon(Icons.wb_sunny_rounded),
            onPressed: () {},
          ),
        ],
        title: Text(
          "Search...",
          style: GoogleFonts.lato(
              fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.w600, color: Colors.white),
        ),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: white.withAlpha(150),
              ),
              child: SingleChildScrollView(
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                  children: [
                    ClipRRect(
                      child: SizedBox(
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                            horizontal: 9,
                            // vertical: 10,
                          ),
                          child: Container(
                            height: 44,
                            margin: const EdgeInsets.all(9),
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 5),
                            decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(
                                  10.0)), // set rounded corner radius
                            ),
                            child: Center(
                              child: TextFormField(
                                obscureText: false,
                                controller: searchUsernameController,
                                onChanged: (val) {
                                  searchUsernameController.text = val;
                                },
                                style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.black54),
                                decoration: InputDecoration(
                                  enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                                    borderSide: const BorderSide(
                                        color: Colors.black87, width: 0.0),
                                  ),
                                  focusedBorder: const OutlineInputBorder(
                                    borderRadius:
                                        BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
                                    borderSide: BorderSide(
                                        color: Colors.blueAccent, width: 0.7),
                                  ),
                                  hintText: 'Search Username...',
                                  hintStyle: const TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 17, color: Colors.black54),
                                  suffixIcon: IconButton(
                                    onPressed: () {
                                      initiateSearch();
                                    },
                                    icon: const Icon(Icons.search),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    searchList(),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

getChatRoomId(String ab, ba) {
  if (ab.substring(0, 1).codeUnitAt(0) > ba.substring(0, 1).codeUnitAt(0)) {
    return "$ba\_$ab";
  } else {
    return "$ab\_$ba";
  }
}
```

What do I do to get rid of the problem because it was working initially.

Comment: What happen when you remove navigator

Comment: Nothing happened. But it was initially working

Comment: does it show any error without navigator? btw you are having range error

Comment: It shows the same error as stated in the question

Comment: put `await _database.createChatRoom...` I think it maybe future

Comment: It still didn't work

Comment: try with printing  `users`  and commenting rest code

Comment: have you already checked? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54977982/rangeerror-index-invalid-value-valid-value-range-is-empty-0; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59872669/rangeerror-index-invalid-value-only-valid-value-is-0-1; https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KkHq5fzV-u0

Answer (score 0):

the error comes from this function

```
getChatRoomId(String ab, ba) {
    if (ab.substring(0, 1).codeUnitAt(0) > ba.substring(0, 1).codeUnitAt(0)) {
       return "$ba\_$ab";
    } else {
       return "$ab\_$ba";
    }
}
```

one of the strings passed to it (ab or ba) is empty so when you call `.substring` it throws this exception